# High CPU usage with system.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int) in C# asp.net core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working with C# asp.net core 6 MVC and I'm having high CPU usage.
I've been using dotnet-trace and it seems to be system.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int) the responsable for this. I understand that this has to do with graphics. Which could be right because in my app when I ran the dotnet-trace I had multiple uploads of images.

I will left below an image and the code in C# that saves the images that I get.

application functionality: The user send us images from a mobile app and we save the images and data into the server (Linux server) and database.

[image]

C# code:

```
[Route("routToWeb")]
    public async Task<string> saveImages()
    {            
        try
        {
            string[] dividirFilePath, fechaSinPunto;
            string dir = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            string ruta, consulta, strCompleta;
            List<PedidoViewModel> verificarDato;
            var dirPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/imgAndroid/", dir);

            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            }

            string[] dividir, remitoDeVuelta;
            int cont = 0;
            while ((cont + 1) <= this.Request.Form.Files.Count)
            {
                try
                {
                    var fileName = this.Request.Form.Files[cont].FileName; 
                    if (fileName.Contains("/Pictures/"))
                    {
                        dividirFilePath  = fileName.Split("Pictures/");
                        fileName = dividirFilePath[1];
                    }

                    strCompleta = dir + "/" + fileName;

                    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/imgAndroid/", strCompleta);

                    if (filePath.Contains("/Pictures/"))
                    {
                        dividirFilePath = filePath.Split("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/");
                        filePath = dividirFilePath[0] + dividirFilePath[1];
                    }

                    dividir = fileName.Split("_");

                    // dividir[2] = dividir[2].Remove(4);
                    remitoDeVuelta = dividir[2].Split("-");

                    verificarDato = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
                    consulta = "SELECT p.Pedido, p.Entrega, p.Remito FROM Pedido p WHERE Remito = '" + remitoDeVuelta[0] + remitoDeVuelta[1] + "' AND Entrega = '" + dividir[1] + "';";
                    verificarDato = VerificarDato(consulta);

                    if (verificarDato.Count == 0)
                    {
                        consulta = "INSERT INTO Pedido (Pedido, Entrega, Remito) VALUES " + " ('" + dividir[0] + "','" + dividir[1] + "','" + remitoDeVuelta[0] + remitoDeVuelta[1] + "');";

                        if (!InsertConexionMySql(consulta)) return "fallo en la subida BD";
                    }

                    ruta = "/imgAndroid/" + strCompleta;
                    
                    fechaSinPunto = dividir[4].Split(".");
                    consulta = "INSERT INTO Entrega (Entrega, Path, Fecha, NombreUsuario, GrupoUsuario) VALUES" + " ('" + dividir[1] + "','" + ruta + "','" + dividir[3] + " " + fechaSinPunto[0] + "','-','-');";

                    if (!InsertConexionMySql(consulta)) return "fallo en la subida BD";

                    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        await this.Request.Form.Files[cont].CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                    cont++;                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: Post() 1er catch");
                    return "Subida fallida." + ex.ToString();
                }

            }
            Logger.Debug("Posteo de imagenes subida exitosa || Funcion: Post()");
            return "Subida exitosa";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: Post() 2do catch");
            return "fallo en la subida.";
        }
    }
```

Someone know how could I resolve this? Or tell me where to look please? Thank you very much!

Comment: where do you use the semaphore? you didn't provide any code that is using it

Comment: Thank you for your comment @theemee! I didn't provide code because i don't call semaphore. I think that maybe it is called implicitly. maybe for this line `await this.Request.Form.Files[cont].CopyToAsync(stream);` but I am not sure.

Comment: well, you should find where it is called

Comment: the profiler should be able to provide one or more callstacks that shows where the offending method is called from. Without that information there is little to go on.